# How can I add multiple events to the calendar in Excel without overlapping?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

so I have a calendar made in Excel with 3 cells under each date which is where I want the events to populate, however I don't really know the exact formula to do that. Currently I have a table with the events and I'm using the following formula to highlight the dates the events fall on:

`IF(B4="",FALSE,SUMPRODUCT((B4>=INDIRECT("Table7[Start]"))*(B4<=INDIRECT("Table7[End]"))))`

Where B4 is the starting date of the calendar, Table7 is the table of events, Start is the start date of the event and End is the end date of the events.

[image]

If anyone can let me know how I can upload an excel sheet I can go ahead and upload that too!

Comment: u can use [google drive](http://www.drive.google.com) and share the link